# X and Y variable points on sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

> If $X$ and $Y$ are variable points on the sides $CA$, $AB$ of triangle $ABC$ such that $\frac{CX}{CA}+ \frac{AB}{AY}=1$, prove that $XY$ passes through a fixed point.

Here's what I tried

Extend $xy$ to meet $BC$ at $Z$

Now by Menelaus theorem,

\begin{align}\frac{XA}{CX}\cdot \frac{YB}{AY} \cdot \frac{ZC}{BZ} &=-1\\\\
\frac{YB}{AY}+1&= 1- \frac{BZ}{ZC}\cdot \frac{CX}{CA} \tag{adding 1 both sides}\\\\
\frac{AB}{AY} &=  1- \frac{BZ}{ZC}\cdot\frac{CX}{CA}\\\\
1- \frac{CX}{CA}&= 1- \frac{BZ}{ZC}\cdot\frac{CX}{CA}\\\\
BZ&=ZC \end{align}

i don't know what this means can you show where am I wrong!

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram? If not, this might help you understand and if you have, adding it here might help others follow your thought process

Comment: Is CX / CA + AB / AY = 1 correct?  If Y is a point on AB won't AB / AY always be at least one?  And CX / CA can never be negative if it's just the ratio of two lengths.  Is there possibly a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see this is not true. Say $AX = x$, $AY =y$, $AB =c$ and $AC = b$. Then we get $$ y={bc\over x}$$

I draw this in Geogebra and there is no evidence of fixed point.